# Send multiple emails with sendgrid API

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Hey developers I want to send multiple message to sendgrid (one request). I tested this with nodejs and I can see that by using sendMultiple(messages) method passing an array of messages provided by sendgrid (@sendgrid/mail) I can achieve that however I will like to know if the is any endpoint in sendgrid to do the same thing. I tried to use "/mail/send" but its does not seem to take an array.

Please help.

=========================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of sendMultiple the SendGrid Node.js library, I could see the library is [making multiple HTTP requests to the Send API in parallel](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/b8125d86134157a462c2e24816cfa56677ab76a8/packages/mail/src/classes/mail-service.js#L165-L167). So, unfortunately, they're not sending all emails as one HTTP requests.

Using the SendGrid Send API, you can send multiple emails using a single HTTP request by using **personalizations**, but they have to share the same content. You can however use substitutions to make your content templated and have the substitution tokens replaced with your substitution values. Here's [a sample that shows how to send emails using personalization and substitutions](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/multiple-emails-personalizations-with-substitutions.md).

Instead of substitutions, you can also use [dynamic email templates](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/transactional-templates.md), but the concept is the same where you use a single template and provide a personalization for each recipient.